# Regex - replace non-unicode characters but only in certain patterns

Tags: python, regex, django

I'm working with Django, trying to autogenerate templates for a whole bunch of links, some of which have non-unicode characters (e.g. `é`, `ç`, etc). While putting those characters in filenames seems to work when I'm browsing on my own computer, django does not like it and refuses to render them. I figured a quick solution to this would be to just regex-replace these characters with underscores or something, but only in the urls where Django would otherwise have problems.

The string I'm trying to parse - the autogenerated template - looks something like this:

```
desc = """...blah blah blah <a href="{% url 'myproject:do_thing'  arg_name='ñôt-unìcodé' %}">Link Text Ñôt Unìcodé</a> blah blah blah ..."""
```

So I want to use regex to change `ñôt-unìcodé` to `__t-un_cod_`, while leaving `Ñôt Unìcodé` untouched. Here's what I've tried:

```
re.findall(r"'arg_name='(([^'])+?)'", desc)
```

I intend for this to give me a parseable list of all the individual characters, which could then be replaced on an individual basis via `re.sub`:

```
['ñ', 'ô', 't', '-', 'u', 'n', 'ì', 'c', 'o', 'd', 'é', ...]
```

But instead I end up with the entire string and just the last letter:

```
[('ñôt-unìcodé', 'é'), ...]
```

What am I misunderstanding here?

(I've found both parts of this question individually on stackoverflow, in different languages, but not at the same time - I'm having trouble combining those answers, though.)

Comment: All these characters are "unicode".

Comment: Make as set of all valid characters eg `[a-zA-Z0-9/_.-]` Then negate it `[^a-zA-Z0-9/_.-]` and use `re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z0-9/_.-]", "_", text)` to convert all unwanted characters in `text` to `_`

Comment: Capture the part between single quotes and turn it into a list: [`[list(x) for x in re.findall(r"arg_name='([^']+)'", desc)]`](https://ideone.com/NGPeey)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding `+` to the capturing group: `([^'])+`

Capturing groups 'cannot' be repeated. If they are, you will just get the last occurrence on the capturing group.

So here `[('ñôt-unìcodé', 'é'), ...]`, the first is the whole match. And the last one is the capturing group (the last letter).

Try to use instead `arg_name='([^']+)'` or even `arg_name='[^']+'`

Comment: Thanks for this insight - I ended up using this solution and then iterating through that with a `for` loop doing basic `string.replace()`.